# Postman deletes backslash automatically from the response

Tags: postman

When I try to get a value from the response (the one wihich contains the double backslash), I save it in globals and it saves it with one less backslash

This is the response

[image]

This are the values that Postman saves

[image]

This is the Tests part of the request

[image]

I need Postman to keep the double backslash. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The backslash isn't going anywhere. Backslashes have a special meaning. In combination with other characters, they represent special (escape) characters. `\n` is a newline, for example, and `\\` is a literal backslash.

Postman is most likely unescaping the value in the globals/environment tab by replacing all escape characters with their literal meanings. For instance, if the value included a "\n", you would probably see a newline.

The server is probably sending something like `<uuid>\ORIGINAL IMAGE FRONT`, but you are seeing the escaped value in the JSON representation.